# How to fix non appearing reference figures in Texstudio

Tags: cross-referencing

I am using Texstudio for writing my reports. I am facing a problem of having some of the figures being referenced correctly and the other shows ??. I have ran it twice using F6, F11, F6 and lastly F6 but the problem is still there. I would appreciate any help.
Also I am wondering how to write dimensional formula such as ML^2/T^2 in a professional way in latex. I searched a lot but didn't reach what I want. Thanks again.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{tunnel.png}
\caption{Numerical model of the soil-tunnel system using DEM.}
\label{fig:Soil_Deposit3}
\end{figure}
```

Thus is the way I defined a figure and use \ref{Soil_Deposit3} in my writing. Sorry for my many questions but how can I guarantee having the defined table where I define it because when I am compiling it to pdf it shows the table far away from where it is defined.

```
Energy & 1/ N^{3}  & ML^{2}/T^{2} \\
```

Comment: You miss the fig prefix: `\ref{fig:Soil_Deposit3}`

Comment: Thanks so much. Can you help me with the other questions please.